# getting parameters from URL

Tags: url, php-5.4, search

Below is a section of our URL.

> ...&dir=asc&limit=20&np=1&order=price&product_applications_year=710&product_type=623

I need to search this string for various things like 'limit' or 'product_type' or 'order' and retrieve the conents of that thing after the '='.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('name_of_the_parameter')
```

Comment: Just that easy huh...